# Can I create an alias for a generic function? I get error "Cannot use generic function without instantiation"

Tags: function, go, generics, instantiation

I can define a generic function:

```golang
package hello

func IsZero[T int64|float64](value T) bool {
   return value == 0
}
```

Then if I try to alias that function in another package, it fails:

```golang
package world

import "hello"

var IsZero = hello.IsZero
```

The above doesn't compile with:

> cannot use generic function hello.IsZero without instantiation

Instead this works:

```
var IsZero = hello.IsZero[int64]
```

Is it possible to do this, using some other syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is small, like in the question, it's probably easier to just vendor it:

```golang
package vendor

func thisIsJustCopy[T int64|float64](value T) bool {
   return value == 0
}
```

but if the function is big, you can do it like this:

```golang
package world
import "hello"

func IsZero[T int64|float64](value T) bool {
   return hello.IsZero(value)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't declare a variable but just a new "generic" function.

Answer (score 4):

That's not an alias. And you already have your answer, actually. But if you want a formal reference, from the language specs, [Instantiations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations):

> A generic function that is is not called requires a type argument list for instantiation

So when you attempt to initialize a variable of function type, the function `hello.IsZero` is not called, and therefore requires instantiation with specific type parameters:

```
// not called, instantiated with int64
var IsZero = hello.IsZero[int64]
```

At this point the variable (let's give it a different name for clarity) `zeroFunc` has a concrete function type:

```
    var zeroFunc = IsZero[int64]
    fmt.Printf("type: %T\n", zeroFunc)
```

Prints:

```
type: func(int64) bool
```

This might or might not be what you want, as this effectively monomorphises the function.

If you just want to have a local symbol, with the same implementation (or a tweaked version thereof), declaring a "wrapper" function works. Just remember that the type parameters of your wrapper can only be *as strict* or *stricter* than the wrapped one's

E.g. Given

```
IsZero[T int64 | float64](v T)
```

your wrapper can **not** be

```
WrapIsZeroPermissive[T int64 | float64 | complex128](v T) bool {
    return IsZero(v) // does not compile, T's type set is a superset
}
```

but **can** be

```
WrapIsZeroStricter[T int64](v T) bool {
    return IsZero(v) // ok, T's type set is a subset
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> I try to alias that function in another package

Aliases work for types only. Your code just tries to declare a variable.

> Is it possible to do this, using some other syntax?

No.